# jQuery animation to show the flow of slidedown, show and fade out

Tags: jquery

I would like to ask how is it possible for me to create a animation flow to show an update status, which will be animated through the flow of:

1. Form updated successfully
2. SlideDown to display the success status message within a div
3. Show this message for 5 seconds
4. Fade out the message after 5 seconds is up

This is what I have so far...

```
$("#status").empty().append("successfully updated." );
$('#status').slideDown('fast', function() {
    $("#status").show(5000, function() {
        $("#status").fadeOut('slow');
    });
});
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way:
HTML:

```
<form ...></form>
<div id="message" style="display:none;">Update successfull</div>
```

Javascript:

```
 $('#message').slideDown().delay(5000).fadeOut();
```

**EDIT** Modifying the code you just added, you should do it like this:

```
$("#status").empty().append("successfully updated." );
$('#status').slideDown('fast', function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#status").fadeOut('slow');
    }, 5000);
});
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#myDiv").text("update successfull").slideDown().fadeOut(5000);
```